# Autofac: Batch registration of open-generic types

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I got an assembly with many concrete types that implement `IHandler<TCommand>`, such as the following:

```
public class MoveCustomerHandler : IHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>
{
    void IHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>.Handle(MoveCustomerCommand c)
    {
        // some business logic for moving a customer.
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm registering them one by one as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<MoveCustomerHandler>()
    .As<IHandler<MoveCustomerCommand>>();

builder.RegisterType<ProcessOrderHandler>()
    .As<IHandler<ProcessOrderCommand>>();

builder.RegisterType<SomeOtherFancyHandler>()
    .As<IHandler<SomeOtherFancyCommand>>();

// Many handler registrations here...
```

The command handlers are injected using constructor injection, as can be seen below:

```
public class OrderController
{
    private readonly IHandler<ProcessOrderCommand> handler;

    public OrderController(IHandler<ProcessOrderCommand> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to batch register all my handlers in an easy way using Autofac?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a similar style to Jim's answer but taking advantage of `AsClosedTypesOf`:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = GetYourAssemblies();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandler<>));
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this, although I'm not sure how IsAssignable() behaves with open generics.

```
Assembly[] assemblies = GetYourAssemblies();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IHandler<>)))
    .AsSelf()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure what you try to accomplish here. The `Type.GetCustomAttributes()` method returns an `object[]`, so how is that going to help me?

Comment: My bad. I tried to copy/paste and edit in the browser text box. I edited out that part.